# Start two apps and loop

Tags: windows, batch-file, if-statement

Im not a programmer. I just using google, to make my life easyer and just would like to make a simple batch file to start 2 apps, and at the end of the batch a simple question, does it work? y/n, if n return to the beginning if y just quit.
I tried to make some code, but it doesn`t working :/

```
@echo off

    IF %F%=="n" (
    echo -=[Starting WattTool]=-
        echo:
            start /d d:\bitkojn\wtool\ wattstart.bat

    echo -=[Starting Miner]=-
        echo:
            start /d d:\bitkojn\cdm\ start.bat
        )

    ELSE (
        exit
        )   
            echo --==[confirm]==--
            SET /p %F%=Does it work? y/n 
            goto :eof

pause
```

I using the same miners with my brother, and making this to him if something going wrong, to save him some time, just hit this batch and can leave the miners there untill i`m back and check what was the prbolem, why they stopped.
Thanks

Comment: What, exactly, is failing when "it doesn't working"? Please edit the question to include exact error messages, if any, and a description of what you expect to happen, and what is actually happening that differs from your expectations.

Comment: there is no error message. the bat can`t start at all. just flash once and gone. i tried to include a "pause" but didn`t stopped the cmd, just gone after a sec.

Comment: To see the error, open a command prompt and run the script from there instead of double-clicking it.

Comment: You have an Else exit before user prompt, the entire layout does not really make sense. You need to think about this process. anyway, will post an answer for you

Comment: I would suggest that you do not use start as a file name for an executable file, _especially when there is an internal command named start!_

Answer (score 2):

If I have realy understand what you want, try this :

```
@ECHO OFF

:LAUCH
ECHO -=[Starting WattTool]=-
START /d d:\bitkojn\wtool\ wattstart.bat
ECHO -=[Starting Miner]=-
START /d d:\bitkojn\cdm\ start.bat
SET /p F=Does it work? y/n
IF %F%==n GOTO LAUCH
PAUSE
```